# Gauge condition in Maxwell's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, electromagnetism

Maxwell's equations (differential forms formulation) read
$$
dF = 0 \\
\partial^a F_{ab} = -j_b
$$
where $j_b$ is the current-density 1-form. The first equation tells us there is some 1-form $A$ so that $F_{ab} = dA = \partial_a A_b - \partial_b A_a$. Then second equation then gives the following equation for $A$ itself:
$$
\partial^a \partial_a A_b - \partial^a\partial_b A_a = \Box A_b - \partial_b \text{div}(A) = -j_b. \tag{1}
$$
We note that $F = dA_f$ for any smooth function $f$, where $A_f := A + df$. We solve the equation $\Box f = -\text{div}A$ and see that (1) implies the following equation for $A_f$:
$$
\Box (A_f)_b = -j_b \tag{2}
$$
since $\Box (A_f)_b = \Box A_b + \partial_b \Box f$. **My question is this.** we then solve (2) instead of (1) since this is a nice wave equation. We then set $F = dA_f$. However, as (2) doesn't have any initial data prescribed, does this mean we can let $A_f$ be any solution to (2)? Secondly (and relatedly) do we need to choose a solution of (2) that has $\text{div}(A_f) = 0$ in order to get the right $F_{ab}$? Is such a condition a substitute for initial data for the wave equation?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question per se, but this potential $f$ should still have some concrete physical meaning (look up the Aharonov-Bohm experiment if you're not familiar with it).

Comment: @Malkoun could you elaborate why $\text{div}(j) = 0$ implies div($A_f$) vanishes? If I take div of both sides of (2) and commute $\Box$ and div then I get $\Box \text{div} A_f = 0$, but I don't see how this implies $\text{div} A_f = 0$ (since there are in general nonzero solutions to $\Box u = 0$).

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. I will try to answer your questions. Basically, you have some gauge freedom in choosing $A$. They all give the same $F$ though. So the gauge condition you are mentioning is essentially just fixing a gauge that would make your life easier. It is not a replacement for boundary conditions. Look at EM books, and you will see many examples of BVP with Maxwell's equations. I hope this answers your questions.